# Checking a type of variable contained in List<?>

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to ckeck if there's a object of type of String contained in ArrayList.
For example I've got a List of Strings and ints.
I want to find Strings and delete them. For example, I tried this solution:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> listToFilter = new ArrayList<>();
        listToFilter.add("String");
        listToFilter.add(12);
        listToFilter.add(111);
        listToFilter.add("Poop");
        listToFilter.add("Pee");
        listToFilter.add(590);
        listToFilter.add("___");

        for (Object object : listToFilter) {
            if (object.contains("")) {
                listToFilter.remove("");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(listToFilter);
    }
```

Comment: you mean an instanceof check?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"? Is there an error message? What is it? Please show a [mcve] and your expected outputs.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: the output is `[String, 12, 111, Poop, Pee, 590, ___]`
I want it to be: `[12, 111, 590]`

Comment: so, again: have you tried a simple instanceof check?

Comment: @Stultuske if I use `instanceof` check, there's a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @Chernosmaga that is not because of the check, that is because you are modifying the list you're iterating over.

Comment: @Stultuske so what am I doing wrong? I dont get it. In code preview I didn't use List.of(), I used ArrayList. It can be modifiable

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the non String objects by using **instanceof** operator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> listToFilter = new ArrayList<>();
    listToFilter.add("String");
    listToFilter.add(12);
    listToFilter.add(111);
    listToFilter.add("Poop");
    listToFilter.add("Pee");
    listToFilter.add(590);
    listToFilter.add("___");

    List<Object> objects = listToFilter.stream().filter(o -> !(o instanceof String)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(objects);
}
```

Comment: I didn't go so far in learning java, so I don't know how it works. But it works, so anyway thanks a lot

Comment: for starters you can google "instanceof" operator. you can also google the "ConcurrentModificationException". Those are two totaly separate topics, which is good to know when coding in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code:

```
List<Object> listToFilter = new ArrayList<>();
        listToFilter.add("String");
        listToFilter.add(12);
        listToFilter.add(111);
        listToFilter.add("Poop");
        listToFilter.add("Pee");
        listToFilter.add(590);
        listToFilter.add("___");

        for (Object object : listToFilter) {
            if (object.contains("")) {
                listToFilter.remove("");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(listToFilter);
```

being a String doesn't mean it'll return true on 'contains("")', so your logic is flawed.

This is why it doesn't work. You also shouldn't try to modify the List you are iterating over, that is causing the problem you get when trying with instanceof.

```
    List<Object> listToFilter = new ArrayList<>();
    listToFilter.add("String");
    listToFilter.add(12);
    listToFilter.add(111);
    listToFilter.add("Poop");
    listToFilter.add("Pee");
    listToFilter.add(590);
    listToFilter.add("___");

    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object object : listToFilter) {
        if ( !(object instanceof String ) ) 
          result.add(object);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

This is a basic solution for your issue, though the code might look nicer if you use streams instead.

Comment: Thanks, your code makes sense. The thing is, I just started to learn java a few months ago, so sometimes I got confused